# else if help in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to take two strings and returns the longer string. If both strings have the same length, then the function should return the string 'TIE'. I am very new to javascript

```
function getLongerString(str1,str2)
{
var a = console.log("str1");
var b = console.log("str2");
if(a.length==b.length)
{
long = "TIE";
}
     else if(a.length>b.length)
     {
        long = a; 
      }
      else
      {
        long = b;
      }
    console.log(long);
}
```

Comment: `var a = console.log("str1").value;`?????

Comment: Well for one you aren't using any parameters. Also yeah I'm not sure where console.log value syntax comes from. I highly recommend going through some [beginner tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics) of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this two lines

```
var a = console.log("str1").value;
var b = console.log("str2").value;
```

Also no need to create intermediate variable a & b

It does not make anything logical

```js
function getLongerString(str1, str2) {

  let long = "";
  if (str1.length === str2.length) {
    long = "TIE";
  } else if (str1.length > str2.length) {
    long = str1;
  } else {
    long = str2;
  }
  console.log(long);
}

getLongerString("Hello World", "New World")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```js
var pre = onload, getLongerStr; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre(); // change var name if using technique on another page

function getLongerStr(str1, str2){
  var s1 = str1.length, s2 = str2.length;
  if(s1 === s2){
    return 'TIE';
  }
  else{
    return s1 > s2 ? str1 : str2;
  }
}
console.log(getLongerStr('what', 'cool'));
console.log(getLongerStr('lame', 'yes'));
console.log(getLongerStr('absolutely', 'pointless'));

}
```